# jQuery AJAX url can't be found

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to have a form add a comment to the database with ajax. The problem I am having is that ajax cannot find the url because of how my current url is structured

```
url.com/thread/id
```

I am trying to have the ajax request sent to

```
url.com/ajax_comment
```

If I enter the whole URL it works correctly. However I need to avoid doing so as this script will be installable on multiple domains. So how can I accomplish this without hard coding the url in?

Is there a structure in javascript, similar to PHP where you can do `include('./folder/file.php');` or there is another method to accomplish this?

Comment: @VisioN has a good answer. You can also use the window.location object  to extract any url information you may need (such as the url base...).

Answer (score 2):

Why not to use relative URLs?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/ajax_comment",
    ...
});
```

Comment: This is how I normally go about it. +1

Comment: Yes that usually works, but for some reason because there is an id at the end (Im using codeigniter) it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

A relative url will work. This will retrieve the current domain and append your page string to it:

```
window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+"/ajax_comment"
```

Comment: Thank you, but what if my script is located in a sub-directory (folder) and it is not installed on a main URL. Is there a way to get that directory name as well?

Comment: Do you mean a subdomain such as the `graph` in `https://graph.facebook.com`? If so, `window.location.hostname` will contain `graph.facebook.com`.